# SAXParseException in OSM2PO

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2po

I am getting the following  error message when trying to utilise an osm pbf from the Geofabrik (latest Europe file):

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

The information on it seem to be more Java related than OSM, but I might be mistaken and it has something to do with white spaces in the osm file.

Can somebody help here?

Comment: Is the file corrupted? Did you check the md5sum?

Comment: The file is not corrupted. Admittedly, I didn't check before. So, I downloaded the pbf file again and this time I checked the md5sum - Same error message.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there are three possible reasons:

1. the file does not have a .pbf extension
2. the plugins.jar could not be found
3. the file itself is corrupt

Comment: Hi Carsten,
reason was, that I only downloaded the SR1. Totally new to osm2po I thought its the whole deal. When I saw some plugins missing in the warnings it dawned on me that something was not right.

Maybe a hint that both of the downloads are needed would help. Guess, I am the only one who made that mistake. ;)

Comment: `the plugins.jar could not be found`. I just copy the main JAR file... duh !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. 
The problem was that I had a long path to the jar having some spaces and special characters like # or !.